# text similarity between two tfidf matrix

Tags: r, similarity

I have two xml text files and using quanteda and tm package, i have tokenized them and tranform to tf-idf matrix. here is my rstudio environment:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0MrJ.png)

how can i calculate the similarities between these two files, for example, using Jaccard.

I have try dist(), cosine(), and text2vec, however, i all encounter errors.

for examples:

> cosine(x = pta2.tokens.tfidf, y = pta3.tokens.tfidf)
>   Error in cosine(x = pta2.tokens.tfidf, y = pta3.tokens.tfidf) : 
>     argument mismatch. Either one matrix or two vectors needed as input.
>
> simi <- sim2(pta2.tokens.tfidf, pta3.tokens.tfidf, method = "jaccard", norm = "none")
>   Error: ncol(x) == ncol(y) is not TRUE

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have a data.frame with string values and you are using distance that need a numeric matrix input

**DIST**

you need a numeric matrix:

```
?dist
```

> **Usage**
>
> dist(x, method = "euclidean", diag = FALSE, upper = FALSE, p=2)
>
> **Arguments**
>
> x a numeric matrix, data frame or "dist" object.

**COSINE**

you need numeric values:

```
?cosine
```

> **Usage**
>
> *cosine(x, y, use = "everything", inverse = FALSE)*
>
> **Arguments**
>
> *x A numeric dataframe/matrix or vector*

**SIM2**

Your error is due to the difference of  the number of columns in `pta2.tokens.tfidf` and `pta3.tokens.tfidf`. Here an example of the error:

```
df1<-as.matrix(data.frame(a=c("a","b","c"),b=c("d","e","f")))
df2<-as.matrix(data.frame(c=c("a","b","c"),d=c("d","e","f"),e=c("g","h","i")))
sim2(df1,df2)
```

> Error: ncol(x) == ncol(y) is not TRUE

But also if you have same dimentions, this method will not work as you can see because it needs numeric argument in input:

```
sim2(df1,df1)
```

> Error in m^2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

You must have matrices with same dimensions and numeric, like this:

```
df3<-as.matrix(data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6)))
> df4<-as.matrix(data.frame(a=c(3,2,3),b=c(3,3,6)))
> sim2(df3,df4)
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.8574929 0.9417419 0.9761871
[2,] 0.9191450 0.9785498 0.9965458
[3,] 0.9486833 0.9922779 1.0000000
```

**A possible solution**

Use function `stringdist` from `stringdist` package, here a toy example:

Two dataframes with string values

```
df1<-data.frame(a=c("abc","bav","cda"),b=c("ddd","ese","feff"))
df2<-data.frame(a=c("abc","gfb","cdd"),b=c("dsd","eeesfd","fafe"))
```

Function to compare string values in two big data.frames:

```
f<-function(i,df1,df2)
{
  f2<-function(y,list1,list2)
  {
    return(stringdist(list1[y],list2[y],method="jw"))
  }

  return(unlist(lapply(seq(1:length(df1[,i])),f2,list1=df1[,i],list2=df2[,i])))
}

dist_matrix<-do.call(cbind,lapply(seq(1:ncol(df1)),f,df1=df1,df2=df2))
```

Distance matrix

```
dist_matrix
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.0000000 0.2222222
[2,] 1.0000000 0.2777778
[3,] 0.2222222 0.3333333
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. I tried your solution. dist_matrix show me the error: Error: cannot allocate vector of size 21.8 Gb. does that mean my dataframe is too large for my computer?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the answer changing the function in a way to manage (I hope) big data.frames. If you want just to make a test, call the function using a few rows like this: dist_matrix<-do.call(cbind,lapply(seq(1:ncol(df1)),f,df1=df1[1:10,],df2=df2[1:10,]))

Comment: wow!that do work! thank you so much. I'm new to text analysis, so I do have another question. what if I want to obtain a single similarity index that show the similarity between two texts, for example, 0.66 means that 66% percent of text1 is similiar to text2. How can I do that?

Comment: stringdist function implemented in my function do this. have a look on its help page to better understand the output values and other possible method to use.